# log4j rollingfileappender rotating catalina.out file but keeps writing in catalina.out.1 file

Tags: logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

I wanted to configure log4j rollingFileAppender in alfresco 4.0.1 as I wanted to keep rotating catalina.out file whenever it's size reaches 10MB. So I configured log4j with tomcat using below link.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

To configure rollingFileAppender I have written below lines in tomcat/lib/log4j.properties file.

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, File
>
> Console appender definition
>
> log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.File.File=${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.out
>   log4j.appender.File.MaxFileSize=10MB log4j.appender.File.Append=true
>   log4j.appender.File.MaxBackupIndex=10
>   log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%x] [%p]
>   [%c{3}] [%t] [%r] %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=INFO
>   log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core=INFO
>   log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.session=INFO

When I start alfresco and monitors logs, I can see that when catalina.out file reaches 10MB log4j renames it to catalina.out.1 file and creates new catalina.out file. But the issue is, tocmat keeps logging in catalina.out.1 file. It should be writing to catalina.out file always, right?

How do I solve it??

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot and then asked in Alfresco support. They have suggested to use linux's tool **logrotate** for log rotation. I have configured that and seems like rotation **is working fine**. My logrotate configuration is as below.

```
/path/to/log/file/catalina.out { 
copytruncate 
rotate 7 
compress 
missingok 
size 10M 
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem, but in Windows (which doesn't appear to have a native logrotate).